# Unable to transmit a string with atmega2560

Tags: avr, atmega, avr-gcc

I have tried to transmit a character with my atmega2560 (it is on my Arduino board) and it works fine but when it comes to transmit a whole string it went something wrong with it. It is giving me a garbage values which I am unable to solve. I have done all the possible logic according to me but I can't make it out.

```
void serialSetup(void)
{
    UBRR0H = (BAUD_RATE_CALC >> 8);
    UBRR0L = BAUD_RATE_CALC;
    UCSR0B = (1 << TXEN0)  | (1 << RXEN0);
    UCSR0C = (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00); // 8 bit data format
}

void USART_send(unsigned char data)
{
    while (!(UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)))
        /* do nothing */ ;
    UDR0 = data;
}

void USART_putstring(unsigned char* StringPtr)
{
    while (*StringPtr != '\r') {
        USART_send(*StringPtr);
        StringPtr++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    serialSetup();
    USART_putstring("rajat\n\r");
    while (1) {
        USART_send('a');
        _delay_ms(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: FTR, it is a bit unusual that you are not using a normal NUL (`'\0'`) terminated C string, but use CR (`'\r'`) for terminating the string. Is there a special reason for that?

Comment: Did you set your terminal properly? Baud rate, no parity nad 1 stop bit. I would recommend you use `|=` instead of `=` when setting bits, but maybe you wanted to clear rest of them in `UCSR0B` and `UCSR0C`.

Comment: If you remove `UART_putstring("rajat\n\r")`, does your program succeed in sending "a" every second?  If so, we know the problem is in `USART_putstring`.  If not, the problem is at a lower level.

Comment: @ndim The null termination is automatic, doesn't need to be explicit when used in this way. My bet is that the \n\r is just for whatever terminal is receiving this message so it prints it properly. Some actually understand the difference between LF and CR, and you have to do both to get what you expect from a new line. But yes, I agree that the "putstring" should look for \0 rather than \r.

Comment: @KurtE.Clothier If the `\r` were necessary for some terminal, why does the transmission stop when it finds one in the string ***before*** actually sending it? The automatic NUL termination of the string literal is not used here. It just wastes one byte each of PROGMEM and SRAM.

Comment: @ndim Yes, I completely agree. In this case, the \r is never seen by the terminal anyway, so it's just a waste. I think I misunderstood your comment at first.

Answer (score 1):

Mybe this solution can help:

```c
void serialSetup(void)
{
    UBRR0H = (BAUD_RATE_CALC >> 8);
    UBRR0L = BAUD_RATE_CALC;
    UCSR0B = (1 << TXEN0)  | (1 << RXEN0);
    UCSR0C = (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00); // 8 bit data format
}

void USART_send(unsigned char data)
{
    while (!(UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)));
    UDR0 = data;
}

void USART_putstring(const char* StringPtr)
{   
    // Every string at the end has a terminator ('\0')
    while (*StringPtr) {
        USART_send((unsigned char)(*StringPtr));
        StringPtr++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    serialSetup();
    
    USART_putstring("rajat\n\r"); // e.g. "rajat\n\r\0" has the terminator automatically on the end!
    
    while (1) {
        USART_send((unsigned char)('a'));
        _delay_ms(1000);
    }
}
```

Note that a ASCII string defined as a char array has a '\0' terminator e.g.:

```c
char string[] = "This is a test";  // contains '\0' at the end
USART_putstring("rajat\n\r");  // contains '\0' at the end
```

But when every ASCII character is instanciated as a single

```
character, there is no terminator!
char test[] = { 'T', 'E', 'S', 'T' }; // does not contain '\0' at the end
```

Also the baudrate can be calculated automatically:

```c
#define F_CPU 12000000UL
#include <util/setbaud.h>

// ...
// Check which bit sampling mode should be activated
#if USE_2X
    UCSRA |= (1<<U2X);      // Setup 8 samples/bit
#else
    UCSRA &= ~(1<<U2X);     // Setup 16 samples/bit
#endif

// Calculated through setbaud.h;
UBRRH = UBRRH_VALUE;
UBRRL = UBRRL_VALUE;
//...
```